# ICICI IMPS payment api not working on postman

Tags: sandbox, api-key

I checked the ICICI IMPS api in postman, but it throws

> Error while sending request: 'Failed to execute' set request header on XMLhttprequest, API key is not a valid HTTP header field name

It's working on icici developer portal, I used the same params and headers in postman.

API url: `https://developerapi.icicibank.com:8443`

Params:

```
{
  "localTxnDtTime": "20200121160503",
  "beneAccNo": "057001510618",
  "beneIFSC": "ICIC0000570",
  "amount": "1",
  "tranRefNo": "17df6a44e57f436492f66f6",
  "paymentRef": "FTTransferP2A",
  "senderName": "APIGATEWAY",
  "mobile": "7588215033",
  "retailerCode": "rcode",
  "passCode": "d1118d6f9fe94696b4b1e1a0980bb396",
  "bcID": "IBCOri00058"
}
```

Header values:

```
API key: xxxxxxx,
Priority:000000
```

Comment: Please check your documentation on how to pass API Key in header. As per the error you are passing invalid field name.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, actually i just copy the header field name and value from developer portal. But error not cleared

Comment: Can you share the documentation here, because icici developer requires an account to try it out ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the APIs mentioned in the developer portal are just for documentation and reference purposes. They'll share the documentation on how to send the requests. In order to hit their APIs, your IP needs to whitelisted by them and then they'll share some credentials like API key, `passCode` and `bcID`. Only after that you'll be able to hit their APIs and test. Also, your requests need to end to end encrypted using the ICICI public key (which will be shared by the ICICI team) and agreed upon encryption algorithm.